# Atcoder ATC001 A 深さ優先探索をC++で再帰を用いて実装したがTLEになってしまう

Tags: c++, アルゴリズム

[ATC001 A 深さ優先探索](https://atcoder.jp/contests/atc001/tasks/dfs_a)をC++で以下のように実装しましたが、88個中12個TLE、2個MLEになってしまいました。
再帰を用いています。
goalの座標も引数に渡して、v=goalとなったらreturnするというのも試しましたが、ダメでした。
どう直せば良いでしょうか。

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> dxdy = {{1,0},{-1,0},{0,1},{0,-1}};

void dfs(vector<string> c, int h, int w, vector<int> v, vector<vector<bool>> &seen) {
    seen[v[0]][v[1]] = true;

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
        int nxtX=v[0]+dxdy[i][0], nxtY=v[1]+dxdy[i][1];

        if (nxtX<0 || nxtY<0 || nxtX>=h || nxtY>=w) continue;
        if (seen[nxtX][nxtY]) continue;
        if (c[nxtX][nxtY]=='#') continue;
        dfs(c, h, w, {nxtX,nxtY}, seen);
    }
}

int main() {
    int h, w;
    cin >> h >> w;
    vector<string> c(h);
    vector<int> start(2), goal(2);

    for (int i=0; i<h; i++) {
        cin >> c[i];
        for (int j=0; j<w; j++){
            if (c[i][j]=='s') start = {i,j};
            else if (c[i][j]=='g') goal = {i,j};
        }
    }
    vector<vector<bool>> seen(h, vector<int>(w, false));

    dfs(c, h, w, start, seen);

    if (seen[goal[0]][goal[1]]) cout << "Yes" << endl;
    else cout << "No" << endl;
}
```

Comment: TLEやMLEを一般的な用語に置き換えて説明していただけませんか？

Comment: まあたいていの人は自分たちの使っている用語/略語が一般的ではないことが多いことを気付かないものですが。[用語集](https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc074/glossary?lang=ja)

Answer (score 0):

`dfs`で`c`を値渡しているために、関数の呼び出しのたびに`c`の内容がコピーされていることが原因だと考えられます。`seen`のように参照渡しに書き換えてみてください。

計算量について考えてみると、`O(n^2)`個の区画を訪れるごとにコピーに`O(n^2)`の時間をかけることになるので、全体としては`O(n^4)`の時間がかかることになり、実行時間制限に間に合いません。特に家を端点の一方とするような長いパスを含む入力の場合に、再帰が深くなり`c`のコピーでメモリを使い切ってしまうことでMLEが発生していると考えられます.